# PowerShell Comparing lastLogon to 90 days ago

Tags: powershell

I am probably missing something really easy here. In PowerShell trying to to check if the lastLogon date for a user is greater than 90 days ago. And if so, then do an action. But I can't seem to figure out how to get those two dates to compare.

I have

$90days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

And then I've tried

$pwd = get-aduser -identity $name -properties pwdlastset,whenCreated,lastLogon

If($pwd.lastLogon -gt $90days)

and I've tried

$lastlog = Get-ADUser $name -Properties lastLogon | Select @{Name="lastLogon";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.'lastLogon')}}

If($lastlog -gt $90days)

Each time I get can't compare, and I understand it is because I can't compare datetime to int64. Just am blanking on figuring out a way to convert or pull either one so I can use it against the other.

The lastlogondate is a translated lastlogontimestamp I thought? which means I have a 14 day over under with the actual date presented. Where lastlogon would be more accurate, 76 days is a lot different than 90 for what I need to do. Or is that wrong? The article this was closed under is all about lastlogondate, not lastlogon property.

Comment: BTW. Don't use a self-defined variable name `$pwd` because this is an [Automatic Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#pwd)

Comment: Thanks for the $pwd tip, didn't know that, I can change that. Not sure if you closed this question, or even if its closed, it just has a popup at the top for me saying it is. but the lastlogondate is a translated lastlogontimestamp i thought? which means I have a 14 day over under with the actual date presented. Where lastlogon would be more accurate, 76 days is a lot different than 90 for what I need to do.  Or is that wrong?

Comment: The `LastLogon` attribute is not replicated, so you need to loop over all DC's in your domain to get the latest date. Initially, it is unset (or 0) so you need to check for that. There's a nice article here [lastlogon vs lastLogonTimestamp vs lastLogondate](https://shellgeek.com/lastlogon-vs-lastlogontimestamp-vs-lastlogondate/) so you can decide which attribute or calculated property you would use best. For all of these, it won't be accurate and you will need to get and compare the values from all DC's in your environment to find the best estimate